# Diferença entre datas com condição (só contar determinado mês)

Tags: microsoft-excel

É possível calcular o número de dias entre duas datas só de um mês ?

Por exemplo 28/5/2018 a 2/6/2018 e apenas quero o número de dias de maio (resultado = 4)

Comment: Isac, são 4 dias. 28, 29, 30 e 31.

Comment: Se usar a função DIAS, devolve-me o resultado de 6. E eu quero saber automaticamente quantos dias de maio são.

Comment: Expressei me mal, quis dizer 29, 30 e 31 ? Porque o 28 normalmente não será contabilizado. Ou quer contabilizar esse também ?

Comment: Sim. Quero contar esse também. Normalmente faria DIAS +1

Answer (score 3):

Uma data no Excel, também chamada de número de serie, é a quantidade de dias que passa de `01-01-1900`. Por isso subtraindo duas datas e mostrando o resultado formatado como Geral ou Numero já lhe dá a diferença de dias. Se pretende obter apenas os dias do primeiro mês, precisa de subtrair os dias do segundo mês.

Um pouco de ASCII art para demonstrar:

```
   |       A       |        B      |        C         |
-------------------------------------------------------
1  |  Dia inicial  |   Dia Final   |  Diff no 1º mes  |
-------------------------------------------------------
2  |   28/5/2018   |    2/6/2018   |  =B2-A2-DIA(B2)  |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

A formula é `=B2-A2-DIA(B2)` formatada em geral/número e **não data**.

Ao fazer `B2-A2` dá lhe diretamente a diferença em dias das duas datas, que no caso é `5`. Depois a função `DIA` dá-lhe o dia da segunda data (Junho) que é `2`, e ao subtrair esses `2`, fica apenas com os dias de Maio, `3`.

Se pretende contabilizar com o proprio dia de inicio o `28/5/2018` basta adicionar `1`, transformando a sua formula em:

```
=B2-A2-DIA(B2)+1
```

Que já lhe dará os `4`.

Comment: Para este caso é simples. Mas eu preciso de uma fórmula que me permita em qualquer diferença de datas, tirar valores por mês.

Comment: Por exemplo, se neste caso eu quisesse os dias de junho, essa fórmula já não servia

Comment: @RicardoSantos Os de junho seria `=DIA(B2)`. Pode até por um `SE` para ser facil de trocar entre obter os do mês inicial ou do mês final, mas ainda assim suspeito que não seja isso que está a procura. Então tente ser um pouco mais claro na pergunta, indicando que casos tem de abranger. Aconselho mesmo a dar uns quantos exemplos de datas e respetivos resultados

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, porque acho que vou conseguir.

Comment: Quando tiver a solução coloco aqui

Comment: Mas imagine por exemplo de 28/5 a 3/7 e querer saber quantos dias são de maio, junho e julho

Comment: Terei de analisar se é mês de início ou fim ou meio.

Comment: Se meio é mês total, se fim é dia do mês e se início é a diferença entre o início e o fim - a diferença de dia 1 do mês seguinte ao fim

Comment: @RicardoSantos Eu parece me que você ainda não sabe bem o que quer, e sem saber isso fica difícil de responder também. Mas parece me  que agora tende para quantos dias ficam em cada mês entre duas datas, que já é algo diferente do que estava originalmente na pergunta (ainda que não dificil de fazer)

Comment: Eu quero contar os dias de ocupação de um quarto por mês.

Comment: A pessoa faz check in dia 28/5 por exemplo e sai a 3/7. E eu quero contar os dias de maio (4), junho (30) e julho (3).

Comment: e não estou a conseguir. Isoladamente é fácil, mas imagine uma tabela de registo com uma série de dados. Pretendo saber o quarto x quantos dias esteve ocupado em cada mês

Comment: Imagine uma tabela com a coluna A referente à Data de Check In, coluna B referente à data da última noite, a coluna C o número do quarto e a coluna D o Nome do Cliente.

Preciso saber mês a mês a ocupação (nº de noites).

Não estou mesmo a conseguir.

Obrigado pela ajuda à mesma. Se conseguir encontrar uma solução, agradeço.

Ricardo Santos

Comment: @RicardoSantos Infelizmente isso é uma pergunta diferente mesmo, com as suas nuances. Aconselho mesmo a abrir uma nova pergunta, explicando o melhor possível o que pretende, para que tenha de facto a resposta que pretende. E dando os exemplos necessários para tornar claro, e não esquecendo os casos particulares que possam surgir. Lembre-se que quanto mais explicito e claro for, maior a probablidade de ter uma resposta ao que procura de facto.

Comment: Isac, a pergunta é mesmo a que expus no comentário anterior

Comment: Tenho uma tabela com a coluna A referente à Data de Check In, coluna B referente à data da última noite, a coluna C o número do quarto e a coluna D o Nome do Cliente. Preciso saber mês a mês a ocupação (nº de noites).

Comment: Isac, obrigado por tudo

Comment: Consegui resolver a questão

Comment: Criei 3 colunas auxiliares, 1 com o número de meses envolvidos, outra com os dias do mês inicial e outra com o s

Comment: com os dias do mês final

Comment: dividindo o problema tornou-se mais fácil fazer as fórmulas

Comment: Coluna do nº de meses Fórmula =([@[Ano Saída]]-[@Ano])*12+[@[Mês Saída]]-[@Mês]

Comment: Coluna dias mês inicial Fórmula =SE([@[Mês Saída]]<>[@Mês];FIMMÊS([@Data];0)-[@Data]+1;0)

Comment: Coluna mês final Fórmula =SE([@[Mês Saída]]<>[@Mês];DIA([@[Última_Noite]]);DIA([@[Última_Noite]])-DIA([@Data])+1)

Comment: @RicardoSantos Fico contente que tenha conseguido resolver o problema :)